# Can we add Tracking Pixel to Word document across all platforms?

Tags: ms-word, logic, tracking

My basic goal is to distribute the Word Documents and see if it was opended or not, that's it.

Bonus, if possible, I can track their IP too.

Here is what I did, I added an image using these settings from my Windows, [image]

I put a link to my server which generates Tracking Pixel and on the server end, it records the IP, that makes sure each time document is opened.

But issue is that document crashes while opening on Mac. And the tracking image does not show when opening on an iPhone or Ubuntu.

Any idea how can I achieve my minimal goal to track if document is opened or not across all platforms?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting idea.

To be honest I think images may be your best opportunity to achieve tracking across all platforms. I can't think of any other way that would be supported on all platforms and there are a lot of features in MS-Word that simply don't work on word versions designed for non-MS platforms.

That said, it might be worth trying with the field `{IncludeText}` and just point it to a blank website. Then you may need some new PHP or JavaScript to capture the IP address...
e.g. for PHP https://stackoverflow.com/a/6837689/3451115

Comment: Hi Umair, curious as to whether (or not) you got any further with this?